# Matrix representation of an alternating bilinear form over a finite dimensional vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, bilinear-form

> For each alternating bilinear form $f$ over a finite dimensional vector space $V$, there exists a basis of $V$ such that the matrix of $f$ is given by $$ \begin{pmatrix} 0&1& & & & & & & \\ -1&0& & & & & & & \\ & &\ddots & & & & & \\ & & &0&1& & & \\ & & & -1& 0&  & & \\ & & & & &0& & \\ & & & & & & \ddots& \\ &&&&&&&0\end{pmatrix}.$$ (all other elements are zeroes!)

My question:

I understand where the blocks $\begin{pmatrix} 0&1\\-1&0\end{pmatrix}$ come from, but the sequence of $0$'s on the diagonal after the last block confuses me. Where does it come from?

Edit: I think it has to do with the radical of $f$ being trivial or not, but I can't seem to find a straightforward explanation.

Comment: It comes from the degeneracy of $f$, i.e. from those $x$s such that $f(x,\cdot):V\to V$ is the zero map.

Comment: How can we be sure that such $x$'s even exist?

Comment: There is not necessarily such a (nonzero) vector $x$. If no such vectors exist, there isn't a trailing zero block. What the problem statement means is that with an appropriate basis, the matrix of $f$ can be written as a direct sum of some $k$ copies of $K=\pmatrix{0&1\\ -1&0}$ and a zero block of size $\dim(V)-2k$. It can happen that $\dim(V)=2k$ (in which case there is no zero block) or $k=0$ (in which case there isn't any copy of $K$ and the matrix is zero).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to find such a basis, you need to do something like Gram-Schmidt, but with an alternating form rather than a symmetric inner product. In particular, what goes wrong with alternating forms is that they might have a radical (with inner products, this never happens). The first step in the "orthogonalisation" process is to get rid of the radical.

Let $f: V \times V \to \mathbb{F}$ be the alternating form. Let
$$ R = \{v \in V \mid f(v, w) = 0 \text{ for all } w \in V\}$$
be the radical of $V$, and choose some complementary subspace $W$ such that $V = R \oplus W$. Now $f$ is a nondegenerate bilinear form on $W$, so for any subspace $U \subseteq W$, we may define the orthogonal complement
$$ U^f = \{ w \in W \mid f(w, u) = 0 \text{ for all } u \in U\}$$
and the orthgonal complement now has nice properties. In order to start orthogonalising, choose a nonzero vector $e \in W$, and take any $g \in W$ such that $f(e, g) = 1$. Now, show that $W = \langle e, g \rangle \oplus \langle e, g \rangle^f$, and that $f$ is again nondegenerate on $\langle e, g \rangle^f$, and by induction you get the basis you seek.